# macOS Catalina, macOS Big Sur and Windows 10 - Triple Boot Plan

Tags: macos, big-sur

With the release of macOS Big Sur, I am contemplating the following plan and wanted to get some advise on any risks or if this plan will even work or not. My current setup is:

1. macOS Catalina as the primary OS - This on an APFS container.
2. Blank Placeholder for macOS Big Sur - This is also an APFS container.
3. Bootcamp Partition for Windows 10.

I plan to install macOS Big Sur on the blank placeholder above; know that it is a separate container and not a new volume on the same container as the primary OS.

I have a lot of customizations on macOS Catalina and will not be able to do a clean install, migrate all apps, change all settings and migrate all customizations in one day. Allowing me to choose which OS I want to boot into will allow me to take it slowly.

When the day comes that I no longer need macOS Catalina all I need to do is delete the container and resize the macOS Big Sur container to take up all the space that's left. Will this -

1. Cause any issues with iCloud Music and iCloud Photo libraries as I will use them on both macOS Catalina and macOS Big Sur?
2. Jeopardize my Bootcamp partition in any way?
3. Allow me to reclaim the space used by macOS Catalina currently so when I remove it I can allocate that space to macOS Big Sur?
4. Any other issues?

Any advise is welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Cause any issues with iCloud Music and iCloud Photo libraries as I will use them on both macOS Catalina and macOS Big Sur?*

   No.
2. *Jeopardize my Bootcamp partition in any way?*

   No.
3. *Allow me to reclaim the space used by macOS Catalina currently so when I remove it I can allocate that space to macOS Big Sur?*

   No.

   I would suggest one of the following two alternatives.

   - Use the Disk Utility to add a new APFS volume in the same APFS container partition as Catalina, then install Big Sur to this new APFS volume. Later, you can use the Big Sur Disk Utility to delete the Catalina volume group.
   - Boot to Catalina macOS Recovery. Use the Disk Utility to create a new APFS container partition. *Enter the same name use by current Catalina.* Next, use the Disk Utility to restore (replicate) Catalina to this new APFS container partition. Quit the Disk Utility and then choose `→Startup Disk…` from the menu bar. Choose to restart from the replicated Catalina. *This would be the one that is not initially highlighted.* Use the Disk Utility to erase the APFS container partition with the original Catalina. Enter a name for the new APFS volume where Big Sur will be installed. Next, quit the Disk Utility and install Big Sur to the new APFS volume you just created. If necessary, first download Big Sur from the App Store. Later, you can remove the APFS container partition with the replicated Catalina and merge the space back into the APFS container partition with Big Sur.
4. Any other issues?

   No.

   However, user [user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894) has suggested the following popup message could be an issue. This popup may occur when booting Mojave on a Mac with Mojave and Big Sur installed in either the same or different APFS containers.

   [image]

Comment: You should probably take a look at [WARNING: Do not install Big Sur on the same APFS container as previous versions of MacOS](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOSBeta/comments/hea72p/warning_do_not_install_big_sur_on_the_same_apfs/). It was back during the _beta_ releases, however, it still may be an issue with the GM release.

Comment: @user3439894: I have Mojave and the just released Big Sur installed in the same APFS container on the internal SSD of a 2018 mac mini. I also have Mojave installed in a different APFS container on a thunderbolt 3 external SSD which is plugged into the same 2018 mac mini. The problem with updates, which occurred with a beta Big Sur release, does apply to the current Big Sur release. However, when booted to either Mojave, [this popup](https://imgur.com/a/hxsTzmC) occurs.

Comment: While Apple felt a message was needed, a user should always assume a new version of an operating systems would offer features that are not supported in previous releases. This was true when I had a Mojave and Catalina dual boot, even though there was no pop message. For example, a verify of the APFS container under Mojave would show errors, but not when done under Catalina. So far, I have not had any problems with the current Mojave and Big Sur dual boot.

Comment: I could put all macOSes in separate APFS containers, but as I already stated the pop message occurs with booting to the Mojave which is already in a separate APFS container on the thunderbolt 3 external SSD.

Comment: So, the "No" answer to "4. Any other issues?" is not necessarily a true statement then.

Comment: @user3439894: At the time I posted the answer, I have not installed Big Sur on any physical Mac computer. I did not see any such message when I had beta Big Sur installed. I am not saying the popup did not exist, just that I did not see such a popup. I deleted the configuration use to verify the answer, after posting the answer. At this point, I am not going to recreate the configuration to test for the popup. As I already stated, the pop message does not mean Mojave and Big Sur cannot coexist in the same APFS container.

Comment: A technique we use in FreeBSD is that we create to identical pools. We install the current OS on one pool and then when we upgrade, we install to the second pool and make that bootable leaving the original intact (in case things go sideways).  The next upgrade goes to the orig. pool and so on.  Couldn't this be done with multiple APFS containers ( not volumes)?

Comment: @Allan: I am not sure what point you are trying to make. I do propose as an alternative to create two APFS containers, The OP also proposed to do so. The difference is which container will hold Catalina and which will hold Big Sur.

Comment: If the issue can arise with multiple APFS volumes on the same container, maybe instead create two containers with only one volume per container?  Would it matter which container held which OS?